# Improving componentwise convergence of probability mass functions to norm convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

Let $\alpha^n, \alpha \in \ell^1$ with $\alpha^n, \alpha \geq 0$, $\sum_i \alpha^n_i = 1$, $\sum_i \alpha_i = 1$ such that $\alpha^n_i \to \alpha_i$ for all $i$. Does it follow that $\sum_i |\alpha^n_i - \alpha_i| \to 0$?

Note: It is enough to show that $\sum_i \alpha^n_i v_i \to \sum_i \alpha_i v_i$ for all $v \in  \ell^\infty$. (For $v = (1, 1, \dots )$ this is obviously true.) Then the Schur property of $\ell^1$ implies the desired norm convergence in $\ell^1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x^{+}=\max \{x,0\}$ and $x^{-}=-\min \{x,0\}$. By DCT we get $\sum (\alpha_i-\alpha_i^{n})^{+} \to 0$. [$0 \leq (\alpha_i-\alpha_i^{n})^{+} \leq \alpha_i$ and $\sum \alpha_i <\infty$]. But then $\sum (\alpha_i-\alpha_i^{n})^{-} \to 0$ too since $x^{-}=-x+x^{+}$ and $\sum (\alpha_i^{n}-\alpha_i^{n})=0$. Adding these two we get $\sum |\alpha_i-\alpha_i^{n}| \to 0$.

An easy proof of DCT in this special case: Given $\epsilon >0$ choose $N$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=N}^{\infty}\alpha_i <\epsilon$. Then $\sum\limits_{i=N}^{\infty}(\alpha_i-\alpha_i^{n})^{+} <\epsilon$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N-1}(\alpha_i-\alpha_i^{n})^{+} \to 0$ so $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N-1}(\alpha_i-\alpha_i^{n})^{+}<\epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Add these two inequlities to finish.

Comment: Thank you, DCT was the hint.